# Retrieve the current scale value of a Matrix in Java

Tags: java, android, math, matrix

In an object of the [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html), after make several calls to `postScale()` how can I retrieve the final scale value?

Answer (score 4):

Extract the matrix values and use the ones you need, for example:

```
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);
float scale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's possible for you to keep track of the individual scale factors?

The "final" scale value of an image that was rescaled a couple of times is the product of the individual scale factors. A simplified example using the same scale for `x` and `y` axis:

```
float[] scales = {0.2f, 0.5f, 1f, 2f, 5f};
```

If you apply these subsequently, then the final scale will be 0.2 * 0.5 * 1 * 2 * 5 = 1 again, that is the final image is again the same as the original one.

If you apply different factors for `x` and `y` axis, then you have to compute the product individually for both axis.